# Help needed with Update trigger t-sql

Tags: t-sql, triggers

How to create trigger on Update in transact sql, to set another field in updated row?
For example:

```
UPDATE table SET true_false = 1 WHERE ID = @ID
```

will run command:

```
UPDATE table SET date = GETDATE() WHERE ID = @ID
```

.
Please help. I can't figure it out ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that you must always allow for the possibility of multi-row updates in any trigger you write.

```
create trigger tr_U_YourTable
on YourTable
for Update
as
begin
    if update(true_false)
        update yt
            set date = getdate()
            from Inserted i
                inner join Deleted d
                    on i.ID = d.ID
                inner join YourTable yt
                    on i.ID = yt.ID
            where coalesce(i.true_false,0) <> coalesce(d.true_false,0)
end
```